# Changing footer of a Magento theme

Tags: php, html, css, magento

I have a Magento installation. In the footer area I want to replace 'FROM TWITTER' block with a static block and text in it. Theme developer has helped me a little which he said I should go to `/app/design/frontend/default/trego/template/page/html/footer.phtml` and find the below code, then replace with my custom code.

```
        <div class="col-2">
            <h2 class="footer-title"><?php echo $this->__('From Twitter') ?></h2>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('twitterfeed'); ?>
        </div>
```

Please tell me what code I should replace the above one with, so I can have a simple static block with text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a static block with the content you want and replace the `getChildHtml` bit with

```
<?php echo ($this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('BLOCK_IDENTIFIER')->toHtml()); ?>
```

replace `BLOCK_IDENTIFIER` with the assigned identifier from your cms admin page

Comment: Anytime.  I like using this method because it allows for content update without editing files